# Deploying dynamically created BPMN model using Activiti REST API

Tags: spring, activiti

I am new to Activiti. I am working on a project in which i should be able to create process dynamically using spring mvc. I have come acrossed http://stacktrace.be/blog/2013/03/dynamic-process-creation-and-deployment-in-100-lines/

Is it possible to deploy the dynamically created process using REST API directly or we should create bpmn-20.xml and deploy it. Also is there any example for creating complex process such as using boundary events dynamically.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible through this endpoint `/activiti-rest/service/deployment`!
Please check [this forum thread](https://forums.activiti.org/content/upload-or-deploy-new-workflow-through-rest-api) for further infos + sample code.

You do not have to really create the file on your disk, just simulate it with an InputStream of some sort:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addBinaryBody("deployment", new ByteArrayInputStream((<put-something-here>).toByteArray()), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY,"test.bpmn20.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for uploading .bpmn file content as string and starting the process at the same time:

```
@Autowired
private RuntimeService runtimeService;

@PostMapping("/deployAndStartProcess")
public void deployAndStartProcess(@RequestBody DeployWorkflow dw, @RequestParam(required = false) HashMap<String, Object> variables) {
  String processXml = dw.getBpmnFile();
  String processId = dw.getProcessKey();
  ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
  DeploymentBuilder deploymentBuilder = processEngine.getRepositoryService().createDeployment().name(processId);
  deploymentBuilder.addString(processId + ".bpmn", processXml);
  deploymentBuilder.deploy();
  runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(processId, variables);
}
```

Reference: [Look at heymjo's answer in the last](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/217447-programmatic-process-definition-and-deployment-without-xml)